# Matplotlib in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to plot a graph using Matplotlib in tkinter. Here the graph should plot all the values of 'a' in the range 0-24. My code is as follows

```
import math
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *

def att_func(d=0, n=0, z=0):
# Getting User inputs from the UI

   d = d_user.get()
   n = n_user.get()
   z = z_user.get()

   a = (-9.87 * math.sin(2 * ((2 * math.pi * (d - 81)) / 365)) + n * z)
   a_label.configure(text=a)

   return (a)

#Plotting the graph
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.nbutton_graph = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Show Graph", command=self.graph)
        self.nbutton_graph.pack()


        f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        ab = f.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = ab.plot(range(24))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

   def graph(self):
       day_elevation_hrs = []
       for i in range(24):
           day_elevation_hrs.append(att_func(i, 0, 0)[0])


           self.canvas.draw()

       return
root = tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)

# User Inputs
d_user = IntVar()
n_user = DoubleVar()
z_user = DoubleVar()


nlabel_d = Label(text="Enter d").pack()
nEntry_d = Entry(root, textvariable=d_user).pack()

nlabel_n = Label(text="Enter n").pack()
nEntry_n = Entry(root, textvariable=n_user).pack()

nlabel_z = Label(text="Enter z").pack()
nEntry_z = Entry(root, textvariable=z_user).pack()

# Displaying results

nlabel_a = Label(text="a is").pack()
a_label = Label(root, text="")
a_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here I am able to calculate what i need. But when I am trying to plot the same, I am unable to. I tried as many modification I could. But seems to be in a stale mate. I am sure that I am going wrong somewhere. but can't figure out where.

when i try to plot the same graph with matplotlib, with out tkinter, it works. but when I try to do it in a UI with tkinter i am unable to.. Here is the code for plotting graph in matplotlib without tkinter.

```
 import matplotlib.pylab as pl 
 day_elevation_hrs=[]
 for i in range(24):
    day_elevation_hrs.append(att_func(i, 0, 0)[0])

 pl.title("Elevation of a in range i")
 pl.plot(day_elevation_hrs)
```

Comment: You never actually call any plotting commands (other than adding a title, which should be `set_title`) and in `graph` it looks like `ab` is undefined.

Comment: i haven't called any plotting commands and ya ab was undefined. i have fixed it.. but still the code doesnt seem to work..

Comment: What exactly does "unable to" mean? Are you getting errors? Does the program crash?

Comment: @BryanOakley It says 'App' object has no attribute 'line' but some times i get 'App' object has no attribute 'tk'. I am new to python programming and this is very very confusing

Comment: Right after your App class definition you have the following line: `root = tinker.Tk()`. `tinker` is probably a typo as I don't see it anywhere else in your code.

Comment: In your post, you need a colon at the end of the `att_func` declaration.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: Should ... 
`self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)`
be ...
`self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This documentation](https://fossies.org/dox/matplotlib-1.4.3/classmatplotlib_1_1backends_1_1backend__tkagg_1_1FigureCanvasTkAgg.html) shows that the second explicit parameter for `FigureCanvasTkAgg.__init__` should be the master. (It's really a keyword parameter.)

So, have you tried changing that line to ...

```
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=master)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't run as posted, but I can see two definite problems.

First, your `App` is a frame that contains a canvas, but you never add the frame to the root window. Because of that, your canvas will be invisible.

Add the following code after you create an instance of `App`:

```
app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Second, you are making a common mistake when defining the button to display the graph. The `command` attribute takes a *reference* to a function. However, you are *calling* the `graph()` function, and using the result as the value of the `command` attribute.

In other words, change this:

```
self.nbutton_graph = Tk.Button(self, text="Show Graph", command=self.graph())
```

to this:

```
self.nbutton_graph = Tk.Button(self, text="Show Graph", command=self.graph)
```

Notice the lack of `()` after `self.graph`. This could be the reason why you are seeing errors like `'App' object has no attribute 'line'`, since you are calling the graph function before you fully initialize all your variables.

Comment: @Sandy.Arv: what is "the same error"? What error are you getting?